# Remote shutdown without disabling UAC using C#

Tags: c#, uac, shutdown, regedit

**Question 1.**

How do i shutdown the computers in my network without disabling UAC for target computer using Windows 7?

**Assumption 1**

I disable *User Access Control* through `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` registry entry.

I feel it opens up the computer to security risks.

I am using `shutdown.exe` by invoking a `cmd.exe` process and passing it the IP-address of the target machine.

**Assumption 2**

I cannot use *WMI* as it seems more of a security risk than disabling UAC.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though you have mentioned that you are using C#, this feels more like a network administration question than a C# code question, and this site is probably not the best fit for that kind of question. You might have better luck at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I don't see how this question has anything to do with C# or programming.

Comment: I have edited your question to show you the concerns there-in, However, as you can see it has little to do with C#, and is a little.. well.. disjointed. You need to be more specific.

Comment: there is [InitiateSystemShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna) function in WinAPI. Anyway, why do you think that using WMI is seems more of a security risk than disabling UAC